# How to show two different ways to update the same router? (manual and automatic)

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, user-expectation, layout, ux-designer

so I am designing a webui for a router and I am struggling with organizing the two different ways to update the router. Here is my mockup:

[image: Mockup]

I don't like the way it looks with two different update buttons, but I don't see a way around it because if I remove one of them, then the user will think that it is required to manually upload a firmware, when really it is one of two options.

Edit: I used a tab navbar to separate the two functions since you can only do one of them at a time. Here is my solution

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to better communicate the user on what each update does. You could use progressive disclosure by having a combo button with two options: Check for updates and Manual update and show the respective UI applicable to each case.